# How to calculates the number by reversing its digits, and outputs a new number

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that reads a three-digit number, calculates the new number by reversing its digits, and outputs a new number. I used Scanner. If there is a "0" at the beginning of the number then it should not appear

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int unity = (a%10)/100;
        int tens = (a%100)/10;
        int hundreds = a/100;

        System.out.println(unity+""+tens+""+hundreds);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the problem with code you provided?

Comment: Correct output:
23

Your code output:
023

Comment: You could add two simple `if` statements.

Comment: Or you just reparse the string you built with Integer#parseInt?

Comment: Your unity doesn't work, since `(a%10)/100;` divides by 100, so 316 % 10 = 6. And 6 / 100 becomes 0. You can use `(a%100)%10;` instead.

Comment: My above comment is silly.. `a%10` should be quite sufficient :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a= scanner.nextInt();
String n=String.valueOf(a);
       n=new StringBuilder(n).reverse().toString();
       int end=Integer.parseInt(n);
System.out.println(end);
```

Comment: Don't use `nextInt()`, just use `next()`. It's a string. Skip the `int a` part.

Comment: I think he use nextInt() to verify a number. I think third line no need you can use  new StringBuilder().append(a).reverse().toString();  no need pass again to int at the end

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are concatenating and printing the output as string.
You can  add if statements:

```
if(unity == 0)
  System.out.println(tens+""+hundreds);
```

Similarly an if statement for tens. By doing this you can skip zeros being printed.
You can also try this:

```
int result = (unity*100) + (tens*10) + hundreds;
System.out.println(result);
```

You can also go one more step ahead and write a recursive function to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int unity = a%10;
int tens = parseInt(a%100/10);
int hundreds = parseInt(a/100);
```

Comment: Why? What does it do?