# Reverse a three digit int; if there is a leading zero in the output it shoud be left out

Tags: java

First of all, a similar queston has already been asked here: [How to calculates the number by reversing its digits, and outputs a new number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911967/how-to-calculates-the-number-by-reversing-its-digits-and-outputs-a-new-number)

I am at the beginning of the Java trail at [Jetbrains/hyperskill][1] and the accepted
[1]: https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2217
answer to the above question is not yet taught at Jetbrains, that's why asking this question.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your number: ");
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    int hundreds = (a % 1000) / 100;
    int tens = (a % 100) / 10;
    int ones = a % 10;
    System.out.println(ones + "" + tens + "" + hundreds);
  }
}
```

To be clear, if the input is 320 for instance, the output should be 23, not 023.

Just to clarify, the only subjects taught at this level is Types and variables, Naming variables, Arithmic operations, Increment and decrement, Strings, Basic literals, Printing data, Scanning the input.

Comment: You want to skip a digit if it is zero? Why not use an if-statement?

Comment: what is with 302? Should the output be 203 or 23?

Comment: Of course it is always going to be 023 in this case because you are always printing the "ones", even if they are 0. You need to make sure that you implement logic that prevents leading zeroes.

Comment: @khelwood if-statements are not yet taught at that level.

Comment: @Sadap An input with 302 shoud be 203

Comment: @maloomeister Yes and right now I am lacking that logic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    var n = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print(n / 100 + 10 * (n / 10 % 10) + 100 * (n % 10));
    }
}
```

Credit for this answer goes to @OlgaAI

Answer (score 2):

you can convert the hundreds tens and ones into a integer. and print this one.

```
int number = 100*hundreds + 10*tens + ones;
System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the problem and the below solution should be good to handle the cases you mentioned

```
public static void reverse(int num) {
        
        int rev=0;
        while(num>0) {
            int rem = num%10;
            rev=rev*10+rem;
            num/=10;
                    
            
        }
        
    System.out.println(rev);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about getting benefit from StringBuilder?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(scanner.nextInt())).reverse();
            if (stringBuilder.charAt(0) == '0') {
                stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
            }
            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```